# Java - Using Xuggler to create video from images

Tags: java, image-processing, video, xuggler

I downloaded "Xuggler 5.4" jar file.
I tried to use it to create a "IContainer" in java, but I get an error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibrary.<clinit>(JNILibrary.java:42)
    at com.xuggle.ferry.FerryJNI.<clinit>(FerryJNI.java:14)
    at com.xuggle.ferry.Ferry.<clinit>(Ferry.java:25)
    at com.xuggle.xuggler.XugglerJNI.<clinit>(XugglerJNI.java:19)
    at com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainer.<clinit>(IContainer.java:1622)
    at morph.VideoInfo.main(VideoInfo.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

This is my code:

```
import com.xuggle.xuggler.ICodec;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainer;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IStream;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IStreamCoder;

public class VideoInfo {

    private static final String filename = "c:/myvideo.mp4";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        IContainer container = IContainer.make();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can [see](http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/5.4/xuggle-xuggler-5.4.pom) Xuggler has some dependencies to other libraries. Build your project with maven or download the missing dependencies and add them to your project.

Comment: Where can I download?

Comment: I downloaded "slf4j-1.7.9.zip", Would you please explain to me how to install?

Comment: Take the slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar from the zip and put it in your java project